# Large nonlinear constrained optimization in Mathematica

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I need to do a numerical optimization involving around 30 variables and 17 nonlinear constrains. I do not expect to find a global optimum. I need to sample many local optima. Before I program this into Mathematica, I would like to know if anyone out there has experience using Mathematica for nonlinear optimization with problems of this size.

Is Mathematica able to generate local optima of nonlinear problems involving dozens of variables and dozens of nonlinear constrains?

Comment: This is not  large scale. It's tiny. Finding some local minima is definitively possible, e.g. with FindMinimum. But do not expect to find all of them.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Why I cannot find all of them? Because there could be so many, or because there is some limitation in the minima that Mathematica finds? I know my system is not very large scale, the question is just about Mathematica's ability to handle it, and if someone has had experience with it.

Comment: It simply depends on your optimization problem. Without knowing your problem, it's hard to tell. FindMinimum uses local search algorithms; pretty much the same as many other optimization tools. And local search algorithms simply suffer from the fact that their solutions depend on the starting values. Hence, you have to try many starting values and even then you cannot be sure if you have found all local minima. You can also try NMinimize for finding global minimizers. But do not expect too much from that.

Comment: You might be able to find them all. But you almost certainly can't prove whether you've successfully done that, or if there are still some left. Is this outcome still useful to you? If so, I think you just have to try it and see. Every problem in optimization is different, and what works for one, doesn't necessarily work for all the rest. Your description suggests you might be trying to do [multiobjective optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-objective_optimization), which neither `NMinimize` nor `FindMinimum` are designed for. So you may need to use other tools.

Comment: @OleksandrR. It is not multiobjective optimization, and I dont intend to find all my minima. I just want to obtain a good sample of local minima. I only want to know if someone has used Mathematica with nonlinear problems of this size before, and if the results have been satisfactory.